# Meaning of squared brackets after return in JS - fn(){return{}[]}

Tags: javascript, json

I've saw this syntax and I'm not sure what it's basically doing.
My current assumption is, that it checks whether the argument is `!= null`  AND `is in the return`.

```
fn = function(value) {
    return {
        1: 'Test1',
        2: 'Test2'
    }[value];
}
```

`fn()` results in `undefined`
`fn(1)` results in `Test1`
`fn(2)` results in `Test2`
`fn(3)` results in `undefined`

I'm not sure about my assumption. Can someone maybe clarify me and tell me what's the name of this syntax construct (does it have a specific name) ?

Edit: I saw it out of this context with random numbers and there for didn't realized that it is basically just accessing it. Thanks!

Comment: Not 100% sure but isn't the function just mapping the inputs 1 and 2 to the strings Test1 and Test2.

Comment: it's a faster simpler `switch` replacement for 1:1 lookups without multiple evaluations

Comment: This is a useless function. Why not just use the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't check anything.

You have an object literal.

```
{
    1: 'Test1',
    2: 'Test2'
}
```

From which you extract a value using square bracket notation

```
(result of evaluating previous expression)[value]
```

And then you return the result

```
return (result of evaluating previous expression)
```

You could rewrite this as:

```
fn = function(value) {
    var data = {
        1: 'Test1',
        2: 'Test2'
    };
    var return_value = data[value];
    return return_value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
      {
    1: 'Test1',
    2: 'Test2'
}
```

is an object literal, so its value is an object reference.

This:

```
 [value]
```

is an object property reference expression. That combined with the object reference gets you an object property value, or `undefined` if the string value passed to the `[ ]` operator isn't found as a property name in the object.

The code prefixes that stuff with `return`, making the result of the property lookup be the returned value of the function.

Thus, the function returns the object property value corresponding to the string value of the argument passed in so long as the argument is a property in that object constant, or `undefined` otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. Clarified my question!